# Could not calculate build plan in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, jar

I downloaded Spring Tool Suite sts-3.7.3.RELEASE for 64-bit Windows, and I tried creating Maven project.

I used the group id `com.get.mvc` artifact id `course-project` and clicked on Finish.

I got following error:

```
Could not calculate build plan: 
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4
```

I have installed apache-maven-3.3.9 separately and have set environment variable.

In STS under Windows>Preference>Maven>Installations I have added and selected external maven directory.

Comment: did you install m2e for STS ? and you can install maven apart and use it

Comment: @Hohenheim yes i have installed. Groovy-Eclipse Configurator for M2Eclipse in STS.

Comment: @Hohenheim please see my edited question

Comment: If you're behind a network firewall, you might need to find out whether it can resolve the plugin. Can you even run the build from the command line? Finally there's an 'offline' flag in the Window>Preferences>Maven which will prevent content from being downloaded if it's not already available. If you have that set and are running it for the first time that might be the reason.

Comment: @AlBlue offline flag is not set. How do i find out whether i am behind firewall..??

Comment: Try running the build from the command line

Comment: how to build from command line. i am new to maven

Comment: `mvn compile` should get you going. Once that works, you can turn your attention to why Eclipse doesn't like it.

Comment: @AlBlue after mvn compile it says build success but in STS there is error mark on project. On Marker it is showing flowing error

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom:2.4 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml /course line 1 Maven Configuration Problem

Comment: @AlBlue any solution on this...??